# Automate downloading a file in Firefox using Python

Tags: python, firefox, automation, pywin32, pywinauto

I'm researching about pywinauto and pywin32. I want to write a script to automate downloading a file in Firefox. When downloading a file in Firefox, it will show a popup to ask you to open or save the file, and you have to choose an option and follow steps. How can I locate controls (items) on this popup by using pywinauto or pywin32?

Answer (score 1):

You should investigate [selenium ide](http://seleniumhq.org/). You can use that and Python to automate much of firefox. The forums there should point you in the right direction. This downloading issue is a persistent one.

good luck!

Answer (score 1):

pywinauto installation has an example (SaveFromFirefox.py) related to this:
http://pywinauto.googlecode.com/hg/pywinauto/docs/getting_started.html

Answer (score 0):

You might check out [Project SIKULI](http://sikuli.csail.mit.edu/) from MIT. With it you can write macros by taking screenshots. The project screenshots make the entire process look dead easy. It's Python-based, too, so it may be the write tool for the job.

Also, if you have control of the computer in question, you may be able to check the box in the download popup that says "Do this every time" (or whatever the exact wording is). Perhaps that will be enough to make the job simpler?

Answer (score 0):

For latest Firefox version you can use [pywinauto 0.5.x](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto) (just download and run `python setup.py install` or run `pip install pywinauto`). [SaveFromFirefox.py](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/blob/master/examples/SaveFromFirefox.py) was adapted for Win7.

Useful tips:

- `app.Dialog.PrintControlIdentifiers()` will print all possible access names for the controls on a dialog.
- [SWAPY](https://github.com/pywinauto/SWAPY) is a GUI helper for the controls hierarchy inspection and code generation for pywinauto.
- `app.Dialog.ControlName.WrapperObject().` ... will give you the most useful list of methods available for the control. In a production code the `WrapperObject()` call can be omitted.